# Kubernetes load balancer Network Security Group

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

How to configure Network Security Group for a load balancer in Azure Kubernetes. Basically, want to restrict incoming external traffic to service for a range of IP Addresses only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard#restrict-inbound-traffic-to-specific-ip-ranges) you should be able to specify the IP addresses you want to allow in the `spec/loadBalancerSourceRanges` field of your `Service`, such as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-lb-name
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ...
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 1.2.3.0/16
```